# Android Development: Where to put static Key/Value Pairs?

Tags: android

I have a list of static key/value pairs that I need to include in my project like this one:

```
givenName : First Name
sn        : Last Name
mail      : Email
... snip ...
```

Where in an Android project would I put this?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a XML file saved at `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="givenName">First Name</string>
    <string name="sn">Last Name</string>
    <string name="mail">Email</string>
</resources>
```

Here is how you can access the values from other xmls:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/givenName" />
```

Or this is how you can access the value from Java code:

```
String string = getString(R.string.givenName);
Log.d("Test", string); // Outputs "First Name" to LogCat console.
```

Check [this Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for full reference on String Resources.

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a prebuilt content provider wrapper called `SharedPreferences` that is specifically designed for storing primitives in key-value pairs.

```
        SharedPreferences mySharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
        mySharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
```

Where `getApplication()` is just used as a method for acquiring your applications context. To get the values back out

```
        SharedPreferences mySharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String value = mySharedPrefs.getString(key, null);
```

That will return the stored String with key `key`, and will return `null` if nothing is stored with that key.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use static/globals put them into your custom class which extends Application. Like this:

```
public classYourApplication extends Application {
    protected Bar myBar;

    public Bar getBar() { return myBar; }
    public void setBar(Bar bar) { myBar = bar; }
    ...
}
```

Declare that you'll be using a custom Application class using your manifest.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_noteit1"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/App_Theme"
    android:name="YourApplication" 
    android:debuggable="true">
```

Now you can access your application object from any activity using (YourApplication) getApplication(). Please note that this is not the recommended method. The recommended method is to use singleton pattern.
(answer taken from one of my question answers)